# The nth element of a series where numbers are divisible by the sum of their digits

Tags: c, function

I am supposed to write a program that reads a positive integer n from the input and outputs the nth element of this series(numbers that are divisible by the sum of their digits.). The first element of this series is 1, and the last is  10^6(First 20 entries: 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 12; 18; 20; 21; 24; 27; 30; 36; 40; 42;......). The code down works fine, but I am not supposed to use a function. So how can I put the code from the function in the for loop. I am getting some problems and I can't find a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int digsum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    do{
        sum += n % 10;
    } while (n /= 10);
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, done, j, temp, temp1,i;
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % digsum(i) == 0) {
            if (j++ <= temp - 1) {
                printf("%d ", i);
                temp1 = i;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("temp1 %d\n", temp1);
    return 0;
}
```

If I input 20, my output needs to be 42.

Comment: Why are you not supposed to use a function? It seems a perfectly acceptable use of a function to me.

Comment: I forgot to ask, is this question from some coding challenge site ?

Comment: @haccks no, its an exercise for university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below code

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
   int n, done, j, temp, temp1,i,sum,k;
   scanf("%d", &temp);

   for (i = 1, j=0; i<1000; i++) {

   /*Implement the function digsum() right away inside main() and create local variables */ 

   k = i; //Taking a copy of i as in the while() condition check the value changes
   sum = 0;
   do{ 
      sum += k % 10;
   }while (k /= 10);
   if(i % sum == 0) {
        if (j++ <= temp-1) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        temp1=i;
        }
     }
  }
 printf("temp1 %d\n", temp1);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you do not want to use the function but here you go:

Place the snippet

```
 n = i;
 int sum = 0;
 do{
     sum += n % 10;
 }while (n /= 10);
```

at the beginning of `for` loop in `main` function and change `if (i % digsum(i) == 0)` to `if (i % sum == 0)`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, done, j, temp, temp1, i;
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    for (i = 1, j=0; i<1000; i++) {
        n = i;
        int sum = 0;
        do{
            sum += n % 10;
        }while (n /= 10);

        if (i % sum == 0) {
            if (j++ <= temp-1) {
                printf("%d ", i);
                temp1=i;
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("temp1 %d\n", temp1);
    return 0;
}
```